# wx.MessageDialog with clickable hyperlink

Tags: python, wxpython

How can I include a link that can be clicked?

```html
about = wx.MessageDialog(self, 
              _("https://github.com/horald/londonlaw") %
              {"version" : LLAW_VERSION},
              _("About London Law"), wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
      about.ShowModal()
```

It works with the following source code:

```html
class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog): 
def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
    self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
    self.Bind(wx.html2.EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, self.On_Web_View_Loaded, self.browser)
    self.browser.Bind(wx.html2.EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING, self.onNav)
    sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 
    self.SetSizer(sizer) 
    self.SetSize((400, 200)) 
    
def On_Web_View_Loaded(self, event):
    print('Loading')  

def onNav(self, event):
    print('navigate...')
    url = event.GetURL()
    if url!="about:blank":
       webbrowser.open(url)
```

When I click on the link, it also opens in the browser. However, the following error appears in the window:

`Error resolving “mylink.com”: Temporary failure in name resolution`

How can I turn off this error message?

Comment: Shouldn't you be accessing `self.browser` rather than `webbrowser`? Otherwise, what is the point of creating it?

Comment: If you want to make an about dialog, you can use wx.adv.AboutBox. There is a field for a website too.

Comment: wx.adv.AboutBox is nice, but a website does not appear...

Answer (score 1):

And what about creating your own dialog?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8*-

import wx
import wx.adv

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):        
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        
        self.btnShowDialog = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "ShowDialog")
        #Button bind:
        self.btnShowDialog.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtnShowDialog)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()        

    def __set_properties(self):  
        self.SetSize((400, 300))      
        self.SetTitle("Test Frame")

    def __do_layout(self):        
        sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(1, 1, 0, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.btnShowDialog, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
        
    def OnBtnShowDialog(self, event):
        # Shows my own dialog
        dlg = LinkDialog(self, wx.ID_ANY, title="My Custom Dialog")
        dlg.ShowModal()

# end of class TestFrame

class LinkDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        # using wx.adv.HyperlinkCtrl
        self.hyperlink_1 = wx.adv.HyperlinkCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Go to Stackoverflow", "https://stackoverflow.com/")

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        

    def __set_properties(self):        
        self.SetSize((400, 260))
        self.hyperlink_1.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        

    def __do_layout(self):        
        grid_sizer_7 = wx.GridSizer(1, 1, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_7.Add(self.hyperlink_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        self.SetSizer(grid_sizer_7)        
        self.Layout()
        

# end of class LinkDialog

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = TestFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you would mark the answer as correct, if you think it has solved your problem, thanks.

Comment: Yes, ok, I would like to. But I'm new to stackoverflow and I don't know where to find the button for "Problem solved"?

Comment: This should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work